# Should I respond a congratulation email when I am cc'ed?

Tags: email

My prospect supervisor has sent an email in order to introduce me to their lab members and asked them to make me feel welcome. Should I respond to it since I am cc'ed on this email? If so, is it better to wait for others' responses, and then, respond to all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to give a slightly different answer here to the other two:

I think this is always a good opportunity to introduce yourself - write a few paragraphs about who you are, things you like to do, what you are looking forward to achieving at the new company etc.

Be a little bit excited for your new path.

Answer (score 7):

It certainly doesn't hurt to respond.  You can say something along the lines of:

> Thanks for the opportunity and I am looking forward to meeting and working with all of you.

Comment: Is it necessary to wait for others to reply first?

Comment: No, probably better to go first actually.

Comment: Being the first to reply could "close" this mail subject and prevent a flood of replies from others. Depending on how many people got this first email, getting replies from everyone could get annoying over time.

Answer (score 3):

It is generally not necessary to respond to a congratulatory email where you are CC'd, as you are not the primary recipient. However, if you feel compelled to respond, you can do so with a brief thank you message.

In this case, since your prospective supervisor has introduced you to the lab members and asked them to make you feel welcome, it would be appropriate to send a short response to express your appreciation. You can respond directly to your supervisor and copy the lab members, thanking them for the introduction and expressing your enthusiasm for working with them. You can also mention that you look forward to meeting them in person and working together in the future.

It is not necessary to wait for others to respond before sending your message. It's fine to respond as soon as you see the email, as long as you keep your message brief and professional.